String to object and dot notation (Javascript)
In the application I am working on, I have some configuration stored in a memo field in object literals.

 {
    JWT : { endpoint  :"https://somelink1",
               clientid     :"consent-management",
               grantType  :"client_credentials" },
    CMP : {endpoint      :"https://someotherlink2",
                contentType :"application/json"}
 }

Using regex and application specific javascript language, I am maching the object part only and parsing it
var auth    = nms.extAccount.load(39010);
var regex   = /{([^;]*)}/gm;
var authObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(auth.comment.match(regex)));

logInfo(authObj);


Normaly I would then just use dot notation authObj.JWT.endpoint) to navigate through the object but it isnt working.
14/05/2024 13:25:47    js  JST-310000 Error while compiling script 'WKF9/js' line 6: authObj.JWT is undefined.
Just wondering if I am missing something.
I log the type and is object
14/05/2024 14:24:32    js  object

At a high level, authObj just doesn't have a property for JWT. It's likely because of how you are creating the object from a regex match, but without a [mre] it's difficult to say much else.

Separate out each function call and the results into a separate variable and log them, that should show you the problem.  HINT: Why are you calling stringify?

auth.comment.match(regex) returns an array - you probably wanted auth.comment.match(regex)[0] to get the actual match (or loop as it looks like you're expecting multiple)  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( will just give you what you started with (a string), so assuming JSON.parse(auth.comment.match(regex)[0}) but then, JSON.parse only works on valid JSON...

How about treating the config as string but sanitizing it towards a valid JSON-string by a simple replace task, where the following regex ... /\w+(?=\s*:\s*["{])/gm ... does match each of the config's keys.
And in order to remove the asterisk suffixed/prefixed comment(s) another regex based ... /\s*\*\*\*.*?\*\*\*\s+/gm ... replace task needs to be run before the parsing into an authorization object can be safely approached.
Note
Whereas the first introduced key-matching regex is already sufficient enough, another regex like ... /(?<=[{,]\s*)\w+(?=\s*:\s*["{])/gm ... is even more reliable. This lately introduced regex makes not only use of a positive lookahead like the former one, but also uses a positive lookbehind which might not be supported by some older JS-engines.


const configString = `*** DO NOT CHANGE *** 

{
    JWT : { endpoint  :"https://somelink1",
               clientid     :"consent-management",
               grantType  :"client_credentials" },
    CMP : {endpoint      :"https://someotherlink2",
                contentType :"application/json"}
 }

*** DO NOT CHANGE ABOVE EITHER *** `;

const regXLiteralKey =
  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/9Uejvk/1] ... positive lookahead only.
  /\w+(?=\s*:\s*["{])/gm;

  // // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/9Uejvk/4] ... full positive lookaround.
  // /(?<=[{,]\s*)\w+(?=\s*:\s*["{])/gm;

const regXAsteriskComment =
  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/9Uejvk/3]
  /\s*\*\*\*.*?\*\*\*\s+/gm;

const authObj = JSON.parse(
  configString
    .replace(regXAsteriskComment, '')
    .replace(regXLiteralKey, '"$&"')
);

console.log({
  authObj
});
console.log('authObj.JWT.endpoint ...', authObj.JWT.endpoint);
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }




I believe the regex will match the first open curly brace (before JWT) up to the first closing brace (after "client_credentials").
Perhaps you can just remove the "DO NOT CHANGE" part of the comment and then parse it:
let authObj = JSON.parse(auth.comment.replace('***DO NOT CHANGE***', ''));
or if that won't work for every case, then the regex likely needs to be corrected to parse out the full JSON text.
